# Is there any other way to insert image in FBInstant.updateAsync

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, facebook-instant-games

I'm experiencing a trouble with this code

```
FBInstant.updateAsync({ 
  action: 'CUSTOM', 
  template: 'play_turn', 
  cta: 'Join', 
  text: `Test user just played. Come join in game!`, 
  image: imagebase64encoded, 
})
```

When I run this code I get an error in console "GraphQL server responded with error 1675030: Error performing query." When i Try to run this without image I get error in console "Custom update requires image or media input" My imagebase64encoded has no error. Did anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in front of your base64 string add

```
"data:image/png;base64,"
```

to make it base64 picture.
so it will look like this

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8CwHwAExQHAgpnk/QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
```